# Angular 6 Failed to compile

Tags: angular6

Example:Tthis is a child component for app component, using command line

> ng g c emp

to create it. what ever created it will fail at compile 
          time.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-emp',
    templateUrl: `
          <h2>EmpList</h2>
          <ul *ngFor="let emp of empArr">
              <li>{{emp.name}} {{emp.id}} {{emp.age}}</li>
          </ul>
          `,
     styleUrls: ['']
    })
    export class EmpComponent implements OnInit {
    public empArr=[
         {"id":1,"name":"jamal","age":25},
         {"id":2,"name":"yasser","age":80},
         {"id":3,"name":"zolla","age":11}
    ];

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    }
```

I got below error message:

```
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './
>           <h2>EmpList</h2>
>           <ul *ngFor="let emp of empArr">
>               <li>{{emp.name}} {{emp.id}} {{emp.age}}</li>
>           </ul>
>           ' in 'D:\Angular\bind\src\app\emp'
>     ERROR in ./src/app/emp/emp.component.ts
>     Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in 'D:\Angular\bind\src\app\emp'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're providing an inline template, the `templateUrl` property in your component decorator should be called `template` instead.

Alternatively, put your template in a separate file, and then you can refer to it by URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do changes in your `emp.component.ts` file.

Angular 6 provides template injection in 2 way.

1. By using templateUrl :
   If you use templateUrl your code should look like :-

> @Component({
>       selector: 'app-emp',
>       templateUrl: './emp.component.html',
>        styleUrls: ['']
>       })

Here you need to provide the link of external html file where you can put your html code.
I have created [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7d16j?file=src/app/emp/emp.component.html) for this example.

2. By using template: If you use template only in your code, it should look like-

   @Component({
       selector: 'app-emp',
       template: 
             `<h2>EmpList</h2>
             <ul *ngFor="let emp of empArr">
                 <li>{{emp.name}} {{emp.id}} {{emp.age}}</li>
             </ul>`
   ,
        styleUrls: ['']
       })

Please have a look for another [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x7wczn?file=src/app/emp/emp.component.ts) using template selector.

I think it will clear idea and difference between `templateUrl` and `template`.

Answer (score 0):

You are providing html into templateUrl ...

Basically from angular2 in `@component` constructor object have few properties for component.html linking

1. `templateUrl` : here we provide relative path of component.html
   file.
2. `template` : here we provide html used in component.

so you can use anyone and provide input accordingly.